# Contract statements and assertions

Tags: c#, java, exception, code-contracts

This is the code from custom `Microsoft .NET` runtime implementation and I have the following questions:

```
    public static string ToBase64String(byte[] inArray, int offset, int length)
    {
        if (inArray == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("inArray");
        if (offset < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("offset");
        if (length < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length");
        if (offset + length > inArray.Length)
            throw new ArgumentException("offset + length > inArray.Length");

        // Fast return for the zero length case, note that this scenario is
        // absolutely valid.
        if (length == 0) return "";
        // ....
    }
```

Shouldn't the statements, which check the prerequisities *(code contract)* for this method actually be **assert-like?** I mean, where did the ideology of throwing exceptions for code contract violations come from?

*I could easily understand the following code:*

```
Contract.Requires(inArray != null);
Contract.Requires(offset >= 0);
// ...
```

But **throwing different exceptions...** *Why?*

It's impossible to handle this sort of exception correctly, because it merely indicates the logic flaw, this error is similiar to `unchecked exception` in `Java`, when you also *shouldn't even attempt to handle it.*

Now - am I right? Maybe I don't understand some underlying principles or tend to over-engineer everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with Code Contracts, it's a best practice to throw specific exceptions in release code, like this:

```
Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(...);
```

**First:** In your release/production code, you **don't want to show assert windows** to the user.

The alternative to that is **throwing a ContractException**, but this exception cannot be 'catched' because it is declared internal.

The only alternative left to allow the caller of your code to handle some exceptions gracefully ( eg: like invalid input from a user) is to **throw exceptions he can catch**.

The big advantage to Code Contracts is that the caller can actually see the exceptions you will be throwing ( via sandcastle auto-documentation, the *.Contracts.dlls, plugins & tools, ... ) and guard himself against these exceptions. Without Code Contracts, he'd have to rely on a (probably dated) XML documentation or even nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried `Contract.Requires` and `Exceptions`. I prefer to get an exception that **clearly** tells me that I am **misusing** a method.

**Exceptions should be used for exceptional things**. It is the case when an unexpected parameter is supplied to a method. They are there to tell you that some thing unexpected occurred.

Answer (score 0):

This is a much used idiom to check for pre conditions. In java you have Assertions, but they can be deactivated at runtime...exceptions don't so they provide a "stronger" contract validation than assertions (at the expense of some runtime overhead though).

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because throwing distinct exceptions gives more information about
why the call to `ToBase64String` failed.  For example, if `inArray` is invalid, a message is displayed
  indicating that `inArray` is valid, along with the kind of exception.  Many such errors are useful for
    debugging problems calling ToBase64String and are not meant to be caught by applications.

Using just `Contract.Requires` or the like doesn't give that much information.

Answer (score 0):

Code contracts supports the if-then-throw approach to make it easier to add contracts to existing code.